# Voip Application Made With Asp.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have to make an application that make pc-phone and pc - pc call with asp.net. However examples I see on the web are generally made as windows application.

Can anyone give me refference, examples, documents about voip and asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a VoIP call with a pure ASP.NET application. The problem is HTTP is a stateless protocol that drops connections as soon as data transfer has occurred. VoIP is a real time application where you need to have a constant connection between the various parties (client-pbx-destination, usually).

As a result, you would need to extend your ASP.NET application with either a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) .NET Windows Forms Application or other component that runs a local application on the user's machine.

Comment: I saw some example of web based voip apps. How could they make that? http://www.sippysoft.com/products/web_phone/

Comment: @Mavera That product is run via a Java Applet in the browser as you can seee here: https://trac.sippysoft.com/trac/wiki/public/WebPhoneAPI