# Web-based VOIP application

Tags: java, asp.net, silverlight, voip

I'm going to make an small call center application with ASP.NET. In this application the user will call the customer. However I've already learnt that there is no way to make an ASP.NET-based VOIP application.

Now, If it can be done with Silverlight, I want from you some reference, links or samples.

If it's not possible, I want some other advice. Maybe we can pass parameters from an ASP.NET application to another application (Java applet, Flash or Windows app).

Comment: Where have you learned this? References, please.

Comment: From another question whic I've asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837662/voip-application-made-with-asp-net/5837782#5837782

Comment: @mavera:I read the answer in the post you are referring.It does not make any sence to me.Anyway, Voip calls are done via SIP.So you should start looking there.I do not know .NET so I do not know what you can do there, but there are SIP libraries in java

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @user384706. After answer in the post i reffering get 3 up votes, It make sence to me =) In addition to that, I've googled, but I've found nothing about asp.net voip apps.

Comment: @mavera:You want to make a voip application with a web based front end?Only in .NET?

Comment: Modules of application such as customer list, reports, stats should be web based and in .net. Because  I familiar with only .net, not java or others. However calling module can be Windows app, or Java or may be Flash based. But I should be capable of sending some parameters to it, such as phone number to call.

Comment: You can call a java app from .NET http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/daniel-at-work/calling-java-from-microsoftnet-21813. For the java app use SIP libraries to make the voip stuff

Comment: Now i should find a java based voip app :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sip-stack-library

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try this way. I Gues I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

What about internet phone services that use a different technology like for instance php or others. Like axvoice or vonage might be using a different programming language at the back end. Will it be compatible with services using other web development languages.